# Is it possible to use Matlab's lsqlin to find a single point (x,y) containing two values?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to obtain an inverse solution of a single point in the x,y coordinates: (x,y). I know how to use the lsqlin if I needed to find only one value (one solution), but not sure of how to formulate it to find me a point that is a combination of two values (x and y). So for the general expression: [x,residual] = lsqlin(C,d), my 'x' this time is a point P that contains two values. I need the lsqlin to return the solution for x and y.

Any suggestions on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, to solve the overdetermined system 3x-y=1, 2x+3y=0, x+y=5 you would enter

```
lsqlin([3 -1; 2 3; 1 1], [1; 0; 5])
```

and get the answer

```
0.5217
0.1739
```

meaning x = 0.5217, y = 0.1739.